# Generate React components in PHP and then render in client

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, browserify

I'm trying to use React to simplify the way I build UI for an app I'm writing. I've got a good proof of concept working in a single HTML page, but I need to split out the JS into individual modules to make it easier to maintain.

I know how I would structure the app if every piece of the puzzle is known at build time. Something like this: https://github.com/jordwalke/reactapp. However, the UI will be built up dynamically in PHP, nesting various components which I want to pass into the app.

My initial thought of dumping the generated code into a script tag and having the Javascript find it has led me into a horrible dependencies hell.

My primary question is:

> How do I pass something like `<panel><group><field /></group></panel>` into the app so I can call `React.render()` on it?

Comment: Building up the UI dynamically in PHP?... I must ask why? React is an UI framework. Let it do what it does best ;)

Comment: What I mean is that I'm nesting the components together in PHP without any regard for what the final rendering of them is. My PHP knows about the structure of the final UI (rows in groups in panels etc.) but I'm letting React actually inflate the components to proper HTML.

Comment: `React.render()` only takes a single React component as it's first argument... so what you are describing will be very complex to to accomplish I think

Comment: You could have a parent component that renders a hierarchy of `<panel><group><field /></group></panel>` elements based on props... and get the props from PHP

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. I'm going to try it but it doesn't feel as elegant as it could be.

Comment: @llernestal is correct, this is the correct way to do this.  By all means have PHP render the container elements for various `React.render` targets etc.

Comment: Hi @MikeDriver could you expand on "have PHP render the container elements for various `React.render` targets"? In my mind that's what I'm doing here but you guys obviously think I'm going about it the wrong way. Really trying to get up to speed with this. First time using React and I want to get it right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @llernestal and @MikeDriver suggested in the comments, I used PHP to build a JSON representation of the UI and had React build the components needed to render the UI.